# Paypal IPN Sandbox - receiving status completed before transaction is finished

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am currently integrating IPN via. a php script. Everything is working fine and I am able to check for different fields in the messages from paypal, and update my database accordingly.

However, if I just click the paypal button and login as my test-buyer, and leave the screen idle, right after login. Then a few minutes passes and I start receiving ipn with status "Completed", even though I haven't completed the transaction on the test-buyer.

Am I missing something or is this normal in the sandbox environment?

Thank you

Comment: I now believe they are recurring ipn's from the last couple of transactions. Did not check transaction ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now believe they are recurring ipn's from the last couple of transactions. Did not check transaction ID.